# How to refactor nested if statement

Tags: if-statement, nested

```
if (a or b)
  if (a)
     //do something
  else
     //do something
else
   //do something
```

How to refactor the above nested if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (a) {
  //do something
} else if (b) {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something
}
```